# Can you call out all variables beginning with "A" to set an if function for all?

Tags: python, pycharm

For example I have a list of variables:
Abcd
Aqwe
Azxc
Bcde
Bqwe
Bzxc

Is it possible to create for example an if function like:

if variables "Axxx" is > 1 then True

I want to be able to do this with all of the variables beginning with the letter "A", so it is less time consuming, instead of doing it individually.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Side note: your premise sounds like a case of dynamical variable names. If this is the case you should consider using a container such as a list or dict for your variables, like Danial Roseman suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written an example I hope you want to have this behavior.

**Code:**

```
my_list = ["Abcd", "Aqwe", "Azxc", "Bcde", "Bqwe", "Bzxc"]
for item in my_list:
    if item[0] == "A":
        # Here you can set your variable to True.
        print("Item: {}. It is True".format(item))
        continue
    # Here you can set your variable to False.
    print("Item: {}. It is False".format(item))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Item: Abcd. It is True
Item: Aqwe. It is True
Item: Azxc. It is True
Item: Bcde. It is False
Item: Bqwe. It is False
Item: Bzxc. It is False
```